# How use output of data flow in the copy data activty in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a excel file which I transform in a azure data flow in adf. I have added some column and transformed some values. As next step I want to copy the new data into a cosmos db. How can I achieve this? It's not clear how do I get the result of the data flow into the copyData activity. I have a sink in the data flow which will store the transformed data into a csv. As I understand the adf will create multiple files for performance reason. Or is there a way to make the changes "on the fly" and work with the transformed file further

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- If your sink is `Cosmos DB for No SQL`, then there is a direct sink connecter available in azure dataflows. After applying your transformations, you can create a dataset and directly move the data.

[image]

- If your sink is not for No SQL, then as you have done, write your data as csv files to your storage account. And if you choose to write the data to a single file, you can choose the `Output to single file` option in sink settings and give a filename.

[image]

- You can directly select this file to copy to your sink. But if you already have data written as multiple files in a folder, you can use wild card path option as shown below:

[image]

Comment: For the multiple files, you can directly use wild card paths as shown in the last image. But if you wish to use the transformed data from dataflow directly it would be a complicated process or might not even be possible. You can select `cache` type in dataflow sink and output to activity but this would not work for large data. So, it might be better to write your data to storage account (multiple files) and then use wildcard paths.